# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setDomLayout' of undefined - Error when trying to make print function work with AG-Grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Have been trying to implement a button that prints the ag-grid when clicked as shown [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-for-print/):

However, I keep getting an error at setPrinterFriendly on the line api.setDomLayout('print') that says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setDomLayout' of undefined. Am I missing something here?

```js
function setPrinterFriendly(api: any) {
  const eGridDiv = document.querySelector('.my-grid') as HTMLElement;
  eGridDiv.style.width = '';
  eGridDiv.style.height = '';
  api.setDomLayout('print');
}
function setNormal(api: any) {
  const eGridDiv = document.querySelector('.my-grid') as HTMLElement;
  eGridDiv.style.width = '600px';
  eGridDiv.style.height = '200px';
  api.setDomLayout(null);
}

export function onBtPrint(params: any) {
  const gridApi = params.api;
  setPrinterFriendly(gridApi);
  setTimeout(() => {
    print();
    setNormal(gridApi);
  }, 2000);
}
```

Here is my main class Items below.

```js
class Items extends Component<any, ItemsState> {
  private gridApi: any;
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      columnDefs: [{
        headerName: 'Store', field: 'store', sortable: true, filter: true, resizable: true, minWidth: 100,
      }, {
        headerName: 'Effective Date',
        field: 'effectiveDate',
        sortable: true,
        filter: true,
        resizable: true,
        minWidth: 150,
      },
         ...
  };
}
onGridReady(params: any) {
    params.api.expandAll();
  }


  onGridSizeChanged(params: any) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
  }

  render() {
    const { rowData } = this.props;

    const {
      columnDefs, rowClassRules, statusBar,
    } = this.state;

    return (
      <div id="grid-wrapper" style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
        <button onClick={onBtPrint.bind(null, this)}>Print</button>
        <div
          id="myGrid"
          style={{
            height: '100%',
            width: '98.5%',
            marginLeft: 13,
            overflow: 'scroll',
          }}
          className="ag-theme-balham my-grid"
        >
          <AgGridReact
            columnDefs={columnDefs}
            rowData={rowData}
            onGridReady={this.onGridReady}
            onGridSizeChanged={this.onGridSizeChanged}
            suppressMenuHide
            statusBar={statusBar}
            enableRangeSelection
            rowClassRules={rowClassRules}
            suppressHorizontalScroll={false}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you give console.log(api) inside setPrinterFriendly function, gridApi seems to be unavailable and undefined

Comment: Yes prints out undefined.

Comment: can you confirm where onBtPrint is used ?

Comment: I am using it like this: <button onClick={onBtPrint.bind(this)}>Print</button>

Comment: can you try <button onClick={onBtPrint.bind(null, this)} ?

Comment: Tried it, same error. :(

Comment: can you provide few lines above and below of button code

Comment: Sure, added above.

Comment: as button is outside ag grid, params.api is not available, use onClick={onBtPrint.bind(null, this.gridApi)}

Comment: It says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'api' of undefined

Comment: onGridReady={ params => this.gridApi = params.api } obtained a reference to the ag-grid API instance;
We added a button with an event handler;
Inside the event handler, we accessed the grid api object reference to access the currently selected grid row nodes;

Comment: refer this link -  https://www.ag-grid.com/react-getting-started/

Comment: assign this.gridApi with params.api and use it inside onBtPrint method

Comment: any luck @Jasmine?

Comment: It worked! I changed onGridReady to onGridReady={params => this.gridApi = params.api } and <button onClick={this.onBtPrint.bind(this)}>Print</button> , putting my onBtPrint() function inside my Item class. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Thanks @Jasmine for confirming , I have posted my comments as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option  of assigning params.api to this.gridApi onGridReady method

```
onGridReady={ params => this.gridApi = params.api }
```

Please refer this link for more details

https://www.ag-grid.com/react-getting-started/